# How does client-side Autodiscover detect that an exchange endpoint supports OAuth2 and a client should use MSAL to connect?

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-msal

The Autodiscover flow is described here but I can't figure out how OAuth2 fits into the mix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3211279/outlook-2016-implementation-of-autodiscover

Any links to documentation / guides or any other help would be very useful!